# Unable to adjust UIIMageView frame with code in modal view controller

Tags: ios, layout, uiview, storyboard

I want to adjust an imageview based on a UILabel's specific text in one of my view controllers, but the frame of the imageview never change. For simplification purposes I'm now just simply trying to set the imageview's frame to a hardcoded value. I've tried the following options without having any success:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.lessonIcon.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
}

-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.lessonIcon.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
}

//This method is actually one I created.. it gets called in the modal completion callback
-(void)adjustFrame
{
    self.lessonIcon.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
}
```

In the past problems like this have been because the view is not done laying itself out and I was conflicting with constraints. Usually this no longer applies once viewDidLayoutSubviews is applied.... but this time that image view is stubbornly staying exactly where it's layed out in storyboard. How can I change the frame of this imageview programatically?

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in one of the occurences of `self.lessonIcon.frame = …` and inspecting the value of `self.lessonIcon` to make sure it's not `nil`?

Comment: Yeah it's not nil, In fact the frame value when I inspect it seems to have the correct value (0,0,20,20) but visually the imageview stays in the same place regardless

Comment: And whats that place, if I may?

Comment: Far right side of the view it's contained in. I've tried changing up the constant cgrect (0,0,20,20) as well (100,100,20,20) with no effect

Comment: Some likely causes are: 1) the view it's contained in isn't positioned where you think, or 2) the view you're looking at is not `self.lessonIcon`. Try inspecting `[self.lessonIcon superview]` using the debugger